# X,Y axis skew line how go up/down/sides

Tags: c, geometry, pawn

I have two points, one start position and a goal position(dynamic). I want to spawn players as they would in a formula 1 race. i.e the second a little to the right and back of the first, third left and back of the second and so on. I have already determined the angle so they face to the goal point.

I dont know how to move relative to the line on the axes. I think my distance moves it sideways, but im not a 100% sure.. I also am too stupid to figure out how to go perpendicular of the new points, even though it's probably just adding a minus somewhere.

Well, I hope someone can help me with this, thanks a lot in advance.

Note: The code is in Pawn, a C-like scripting language.

```
    new x1 = RaceCheckpoints[0][0]//startpoint x
    new y1 = RaceCheckpoints[0][1]//startpoint y
    new x2 = RaceCheckpoints[1][0]//goalpoint x
    new y2 = RaceCheckpoints[1][1]//goalpoint y
    new dist = 2;
    new pos = 0;
    new x3, y3, x4, y4, a, b, norm;
    x3 = (x1 + x2) / 2;
    y3 = (y1 + y2) / 2;
    a = y1 - y2;
    b = x2 - x1;
    norm = sqrt(a*a + b*b);
    a = a / norm;
    b = b / norm;
    x3 = x3 + a * -dist;
    y3 = y3 + b * -dist;
    x4 = x3 + a * 2 * dist;
    y4 = y3 + b * 2 * dist;
    for(new i;i<MAX_PLAYERS;i++)
    {
        if(RaceParticipant[i] != 0)
        {
            if(IsPlayerInAnyVehicle(i)) PlayerVehicles[i]=GetPlayerVehicleID(i);
            else PlayerVehicles[i]=0;
            if (pos = 0)//left lane
            {
            SetPlayerPosFindZ(playerid, x3, y3, RaceCheckpoints[0][2]+10);
            new angle = atan2(y2 - x3, x2 - y3) * 180 / PI;
            SetPlayerFacingAngle(i,angle);
            pos++;
            }

            if (pos = 1)//right lane
            {
            SetPlayerPosFindZ(playerid, x4, y4, RaceCheckpoints[0][2]+10);
            new angle = atan2(y2 - x4, x2 - y4) * 180 / PI;
            SetPlayerFacingAngle(i,angle);
            pos--;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your conditions should be `if (pos == 0`) ...` - the single equals sign is an assignment and the double equals sign is a comparison. Assignments evaluate to the assigned value, and zero is treated as false, everything else as true. Hence, `pos = 0` is always false and `pos = 1` is always true. Also note that you increment `pos` in the first branch so that it will be 1 and then test whether it's one, which will surprisingly be true. You second block should begin with `else`, not with another condition.

Comment: Your calculation of the angle with `atan2` looks a bit fishy, too: The numerator should be all y coordinates, the denominator all x coordinates. Your mix-n-match approach will not yield the deseired result. (Think about what happens, if you shift everything in x direction one unit.)

Comment: You're right. I am aware of the double equal signs, and thanks for the input on the second statement, I'll change that.
As for the atan2, I didn't really get it yesterday. Now I've looked into it and see how it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that your goal lies directly in x direction. Your vector between start and goal is then (0, 1) and the angle between it and the x axis is, of course, zero. Let's also say that each car has a row `ix` and a columns `iy` and that the first car has row and column 0.

The distance of any car to the first car is then

```
xx = - ix * dx - iy * dd;
yy =  - iy * dy;
```

where `dx`, `dy` and `dd` are the metrics between cars:

```
    --------000-------------------
     |      000                dd
     |      000        111--------
     dx     000        111
     |      000        111
     |                 111
     |                 111
    --------222
            222
            222        333
            222        333
            222        333
            |          333
            |          333
            |          |
            |--- dy ---|
```

Now say that your goal lies somewhere else and the the vector between start and goal is (`vx`, `vy`). The angle between that vector and the x axis is `a`. You have to rotate your `xx` and `yy`:

```
xx' = cos(a) * xx - sin(a) * yy
yy' = sin(a) * xx + cos(a) * yy
```

You could also write this in matrix notation:

```
{P'} = [C] * {P}
```

where `{P}` and `{P'}` are your unrotated and rotated points and `[C]` is the rotation matrix:

```
      |  cos(a)     - sin(a)  |
[C] = |                       |
      |  sin(a)       cos(a)  |
```

Your angle is

```
a = atan2(vy, vx)
```

but you dn't really need the angle here. If you normalise vor vector (`vx`, `vy`) so that it is a unit vector, `vx` and `vy` are already the cosine and sine of your rotation.

The last step is to add your starting point to the rotated positions. Putting all this together (in C, not Pawn):

```
double dx = 8.0;        // x distance between 1st and 3rd car
double dy = 5.0;        // y distance between 1st and 2nd car
double dd = 1.5;        // x distance between 1st and 2nd car

double sx = 118.0;      // start point, i.e. position of 1st car
double sy = 6.0;

double gx = 240.0;      // goal point
double gy = 60.0;

int ncar = 8;           // number of cars

double vx = gx - sx;    // vector between start and goal
double vy = gy - sy;
double vv;

double acos;            // sine and cosine of the angle between
double asin;            // (vx, vy) and (1, 0)

double cx[ncar];        // car positions
double cy[ncar];

int i;

vv = sqrt(vx*vx + vy * vy);             // normalise vector
acos = vx / vv;                         // determine rotation cosines
asin = vy / vv; 

for (i = 0; i < ncar; i++) {
    int ix = i / 2;                     // grid index row
    int iy = i % 2;                     // grid index column

    double xx = - ix * dx - iy * dd;    // unrotated car pos,
    double yy =  - iy * dy;             // 1st car a (0, 0)

    cx[i] = sx + acos * xx - asin * yy;
    cy[i] = sy + asin * xx + acos * yy;
}
```

Comment: All your answers were very clarifying.
Thanks for all your answers and corrections.